# If we always put Exception object in catch block, then finally bock is never needed?

Tags: java

So for example if we have `try-catch` like this:

```
try {
    readDataFromTable("EMPLOYEES");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Are there some circumstances where `finally` block is needed?

Comment: Catching `Exception` (which is not a good idea generally, by the way) and having a `finally` block are completely orthogonal to each other, i.e. one doesn't affect the other.

Comment: There are other ways that can interrupt the program flow. There is also Throwable and Error. finally block should be used when there is an action you absolutely must take. Like releasing a lock. The autoclosable feature has made it a bit less useful.

Comment: why is my question duplicate? I know the answer for provided question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there some circumstances where `finally` block is needed?

Yes there are:

1. The `finally` block is also executed in the event of a `return`, `continue` or `break` that ends the `try` block, an exception thrown in the `catch` block, and so on.
2. There are exceptions that won't be caught by `catch (Exception e) {`.  (And that you shouldn't catch them.  They are `Error` and its subclasses.)

(Just about the only thing that *won't* run the code in a `finally` block is an action that causes the JVM to exit.)

---

Note that you shouldn't write code like that anyway.  It is *usually* a bad idea to try to handle `Exception`, because it is typically too difficult to figure out all of the possible exceptions that could occur ... and hence what to do about it.  (Printing a stacktrace and continuing is rarely the correct thing to do!)

That means the idea of "handling all of the exceptions" instead of a `finally` is typically impractical.

Answer (score 0):

`finally` defines block that will be **always** executed - no matter whether exception was thrown or not

So it's up to your business logic do you need to perform such action or not

You can find detailed description and example in [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)